# Use Behaviour Flow from Google Analytics to redesign the website navigation menu

Tags: navigation, user-behavior, case-studies

I am working on a big project to redesign the navigation menu of a website. There is [a similar question](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/62055/real-life-example-how-use-google-analytics-to-improve-ux) that helped me a lot, but I have the feel my case is somehow different.

The website is not an e-shop or something with a CTA, so I cannot evaluate the starting to ending point of the flow. It is a dashboard that users spend a lot of time from one page to another, with a few pages on the main navigation bar and different left and right sidebars for each page. In total, more than 40-50 different links.

My aim is to identify the patterns from Behaviour Flow (or other stats) on Google Analytics and regroup links to reconstruct both the navigation menu and sidebar links.

So, I am looking for tutorials, similar studies, academic papers and case studies that I could use as a starting point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Analytics can tell you *what* people do when they interact with the user interface, but they won't tell you *why*, and they won't help you to discover their mental mental model of your website navigation menu and it won't tell you if your dashboard meets their needs.

So you need to use alternative usability research methods which involves you speaking to some users and performing activities like card sorts (open or closed) or contextual enquiry, etc, so that you can really understand what people think and need.

Google Analytics can only tell you a limited number of things but there other usability research techniques which can tell you a whole lot more.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on "other usability research techniques"? I guess names are enough so I can do my own research then.

Comment: There are many ux research methods. If you want keywords: A/B testing, multivariate testing, behavioural mapping, cognitive mapping, cognitive walk through, journey maps, diary studies, eye tracking, mental model diagrams, interviews, surveys (SUS Score, SUMI, etc. ), role playing. . . These are just some of the research methods but everything starts by talking to real users and watching them use your solution and asking them what they are thinking.

Comment: Thank you @SteveD. Will keep the question open for a day or so, and if there isn't any other answer, will mark yours as the best. For now, a vote up :)